# load csv file from azure blob storage with langchain

Tags: python, azure, nlp, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to load a csv file from azure blob storage.

However in terminal I can print the data, but it is not directly fed to my chatbot, but for a general data.
the code works fine for CSVloader in a local file but not for azure blob storage. I am following the langchain documentation:

https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/document_loaders/azure_blob_storage_file

code:

```
`def __init__(self, conversation_state: ConversationState):
        self.conversation_state = conversation_state
        self.session_accessor = self.conversation_state.create_property("Session")
        #loader = CSVLoader(file_path="data.csv", encoding="utf-8", csv_args={'delimiter': ','})
        loader = AzureBlobStorageFileLoader(
        conn_str="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=##;AccountKey=+###==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
        container="dataset",
        blob_name="data.csv")
        data = loader.load() 
        print(type(data)) #<class 'list'>
        print(type(data[0])) #langchain.schema.document.Document'>
        print(data) #I can see the data         `
```

Retrying langchain.embeddings.openai.embed_with_retry.._embed_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised APIError: OpenAI API returned an empty embedding.

when asking the bot, as mentioned it answer a general data not my custom data.

Comment: It's seems the data from the bob is accessible. Can you provide more details such as your embedding details and code to reproduce the issue. This might be due to short length texts. Is the embedding generated if you're feeding the data locally not from blob storage?

Comment: yes, embeddings are not created you are right, i trried to debug and found it was not created, code:
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key='sk-key')

       

        vectors = FAISS.from_documents(data, embeddings)

        self.chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(

            llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo-16k', openai_api_key='sk-key'),

            retriever=vectors.as_retriever(), max_tokens_limit=16384, combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": QA_PROMPT}

        )  
@RishabhM

Answer (score 0):

> load csv file from azure blob storage with langchain

I have reproduced in my environment and below are the expected results and followed [Document](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/chat_vector_db):

```
from langchain.document_loaders import AzureBlobStorageFileLoader
import csv
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
import os
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

account_name = 'storage account name'
constring = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=pPBW9jWu77SqMK5NLWkA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
con = 'container name'
blob = 'addresses.csv'

loading = AzureBlobStorageFileLoader(
        conn_str=constring,
        container=con,
        blob_name=blob)
file1 = loading.load()
print(file1)

os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "https://aoa.openai.azure.com/"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "8d57a"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2023-05-15"
embeddingss = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment="testada")
vectoring = FAISS.from_documents(file1, embeddingss) 

emo= ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), vectoring.as_retriever())
emo
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]